# DataGridViewRowCollection printing issue (new line doesn't appear)

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

So I have the this block of code to print a collection of DataGridview rows. I want to print each row in a seperate line, yet they're all printed in the same line.  Any idea?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{

DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;

string myStr = string.Join("|", myRow.ItemArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());

myStr += Environment.NewLine;

graphics.DrawString(myStr, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not incrementing `startY` coordinate.

Add

```
startY = startY + 20;
```

before

```
graphics.DrawString(...)
```

If you, for some reason, want to make one large string for each row, make it like this:

```
string myStr = string.Empty;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
    string myStr = string.Join("|", myRow.ItemArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
    myStr += "\r\n";
}

graphics.DrawString(myStr, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
```